# AWS Site to Site VPN connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, aws-site-to-site

In AWS N.Virginia Region, I have two VPNs VPN1 and VPN2 and I have created customer gateways for each of them CGW1 and CGW2 respectively. Both of the customer gateways have the same IP and that is 209.150.xx.xx My first VPN remain stable, but the other VPN remain unstable and get down after some time. I have checked and the configuration of both the VPNs are same.

My question is can we use 2 different VPNs with 2 different customers gateways with both the customer gateways have the same IPs that is 209.150.xx.xx?

Also, once the VPN2 goes down, I am unable to initiate traffic from the AWS side. Can anyone tell what could be the specific reason.

I am using IKev2, startup action: start, dpd timeout 45 seconds, DPD timeout action: restart.
Thanks

Just to create two VPNs, or if this not work than what could be the solution